# Redis -nodejs simple program -ERROR

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am getting error for even a simple nodejs redis commands.
This is the error I am getting.

```
/home/veera/Radha/node_modules/redis-client/lib/redis-client.js:394
var callback = originalCommand[originalCommand.length - 1];
                                              ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Client.onReply_ (/home/veera/Radha/node_modules/redis-client/lib/redis-client.js:394:51)
    at maybeCallbackWithReply (/home/veera/Radha/node_modules/redis-client/lib/redis-client.js:143:30)
    at ReplyParser.feed (/home/veera/Radha/node_modules/redis-client/lib/redis-client.js:183:29)
    at Socket. (/home/veera/Radha/node_modules/redis-client/lib/redis-client.js:337:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket. (_stream_readable.js:765:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:427:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:423:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:166:9)

And the code is,

```
var client = require("./redis-node-client/lib/redis-client").createClient();
```

client.set('test', 'data');

My redis version is ,

redis-server --version
**Redis server v=3.0.4** sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=4e722bd58502cba0

https://github.com/fictorial/redis-node-client/issues/26 - same issue has been discussed long time back but the version they are discussing is 1.2.
My version is 3.0.4.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this library is no more supported. ( Description itself says abandoned project.) Unless you have strict requirement, use actively developed and production ready library like [node-redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis).

Example using **node-redis**

```
var client = require("node-redis").createClient();
client.set('test', 'data');
client.get('test',function(err, data){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        else console.log('reply from redis:' + data);            
});
client.quit();
```